# Is there a way to do select route option in Google map direction JS api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to set preferred route option in google direction JS api v3?? similar to you would select travel mode to 'TRANSIT'.

```
Route options
 Preferred
 -Bus
 -Subway
 -Train
 -Tram / Light rail
```

I see in the actual Google map there is an option to select your preferred route option with check boxes as shown above.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is the google.maps.VehicleType object.

> > Possible values for vehicle types. These values are specifed as strings, i.e. 'BUS' or 'TRAIN'.

Official docs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#TransitVehicle

Comment: According to the doc, it looks like the VehicleType is part of the DirectionsResult objects attribute you would received once you submitted the query, but I would like to set that on my request object. I also found someone reported JIRA for this paticuler feature back in 2013 and not sure if they added yet: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4427

Comment: I thought its part of the transitoptions. I will have a deeper look during the weekend. May be the following google page will help you by doing some reverseeng http://maps.google.com/landing/transit/index.html